# MySQL - Group by hour including zero values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying without any luck in MySQL 5.7  to query and group a bunch of test records by hour a current day, the caveat is I want hours where there are no records to show 0, right now they are missing from the result.

I created an hours table with hours 0-23.

```
> SELECT h.hour, COUNT(h.id) FROM hours h   LEFT OUTER JOIN
> test_result_detail td ON (h.hour = HOUR(td.date_time)) AND
> td.date_added = '2017-03-10' JOIN seq_test_set station ON
> td.station_id = station.id AND station.station = 'TS-5026' WHERE
> h.hour <= 13 GROUP BY 1;
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Desired Result:**

```
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    5
7    32
8    29
9    22
10   24
11   15
12   14
13   7
```

Comment: can you provide sqlfiddle with table structure and some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

I think your second `JOIN` should just be a `LEFT JOIN` and the `COUNT()` needs a column from the `LEFT JOIN`ed tables.

```
SELECT h.hour, COUNT(station.id)
FROM hours h LEFT OUTER JOIN
     test_result_detail td
     ON h.hour = HOUR(td.date_time) AND
        td.date_added = '2017-03-10' LEFT JOIN
     seq_test_set station
     ON td.station_id = station.id AND
        station.station = 'TS-5026'
WHERE h.hour <= 13
GROUP BY h.hour;
```

Comment: That query is including all test stations not just TS-5026.

Comment: Add this to the `WHERE`: `AND (station.station IS NULL OR station.station = 'TS-5026')`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! Reply with a solution and I will accept

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx . . . Are you sure you have the `station.station = 'TS-5026'` in the `ON` clause?